# Excel merging two files by rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a file with 150k records. One column is a link. A link can be repeated in different entries.

I took the whole link column, copied to a different file, sorted by unique and gave it an extra column parameter Type. There were about 530 unique links.

What I need to do is merge the two files, so in the original with 150k, depending on the link, a new column would be added with the Type value that was written in the second file.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to add the "TYPE" information back to the original 150k records. You should be able to do this quick and dirty with a VLOOKUP or INDEX(MATCH()).

Assuming your

VLOOKUP("link","link:type columns in newspreadsheet",2,0)

Where "link" is the link column in the 150k spreadsheet
"link:type columns in newspreadsheet" are the columns with the link and type information in the new spreadsheet.
The "2" tells the formula to pull back the TYPE information assuming there are just the two columns in the new spreadsheet "link" and "type"
and "0" tell the formula to match the "link" exactly.

Then after you got the type information populated you could do a copy/paste values.